# Ember mirage factory create an array using fakerjs

Tags: ember.js, faker, ember-cli-mirage

I am looking to return an array of emails in my Ember mirage factory using faker.js.

Here's the code snippet,

```
import { Factory } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

    export default Factory.extend({

    body() { return faker.lorem.sentence(); },
    emails: [
       "abc@123.com",
       "def@456.com",
    ]
});
```

I want to use faker to dynamically create emails array. This is already raised as an issue in [fakerjs github](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/issues/399). But the [suggested workaround](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/issues/399#issuecomment-274909821) cannot be applied to this case.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more I'm not sure I can fully answer your question, but what about something like

```
emails() {
  return [1, 2, 3].map(() => faker.internet.email());
}
```